# Why does Angular 2's CanActivate return an Observable<boolean> instead of a Promise?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

The [`CanActivate` class](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html) permits an `Observable<boolean>` return type.

The only use cases that make sense to me are:

1. `CanActivate` could 'asynchronously' block a route being displayed until `observer.next(true|false)` is called.
2. I could display a route that `CanActivate` allows then push a `observer.next(false)` from another part of my app and have that route disappear.

However, point one works but not point two. Therefore I can't find a reason why `CanActivate` should allow a return type of `Observable<boolean>` other than convenience - which in turn complicates the API. It would be cleaner if `CanActivate` only permitted a `boolean` return type and `Promise`.

Please note that I am new to Angular, RxJS and everything Node based so I might be missing the obvious. I spent a while trying to extract the functionality from `CanActivate` that the `Observer<boolean>` return type implies.

Comment: It's their decision to not use Promises, replacing them with Observables.  You certainly can have an Observable that just returns a single value before completing, all the http calls are now promises for instance.

Comment: Why not ask the devs who built the router upon which the v3 router was based? [Create an issue](https://github.com/ngrx/router/issues), ask the question, and you will likely get an answer.

Comment: Ok will do. Wasn't sure if it was a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS 2, almost every asynchronized operation returns Observable. Because you can implement your own CanActivate, you may want to do it with server access. For example, checking admin credentials in server. You can see similar example [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard).

If this method had returned boolean data type, you'd need to block the page in order to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It lets you perform some async process.  Imagine you have a `currentUser` observable from an authentication service.  It is a `ReplaySubscriber(1);` and will always return the current logged-in user, but when your app first loads the auth call may still be processing so you don't know if it's complete.

```
CanActivate() {
  return this.currentUser.map(user => user && user.isActive());
}
```

Comment: Using an `Observable` implies that I also get functionality as I described in point two of my question as they are designed for pushing [multiple values](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#observable). `CanActivate` only has the ability to push *one* value before it unsubscribes from the observable. Therefore surely a `Promise` return type is more appropriate. I will update my question with more clarity.

Comment: I believe the CanActivate is checked only prior to activation.  I don't believe it keeps listening to that observable after the route has been activated.

Comment: Yeah that's the functionality I see, which is why I think returning a Promise would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 7 `canActivate` can return `Observable`, `Promise` and simply a `boolean`, and this is also the case for `HTTP` calls, so you can return whatever type that suits you, for me I used both of them as the following:

In case of `Observable`:

```
public getCats(): Observable<Cat[]> {

    return this.http.get<Cat[]>(this.catsUrl, this.getHttpOptions()).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log('fetched cats')),
      catchError(this.handleError())
    );
  }
```

And in case of `canActivate` I used `Promise<boolean>` along with `HTTP` call in one the cases like the following:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    const currentUser = this.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser) {
        return this.http.post<any>(this.validateUserUrl, this.userData).toPromise().then(
            response => 
            {
                return true;
            }
        ).catch(
            error=>
            {
                this.logout()
                return false;
            }
        );
    }
    return new Promise<boolean>(()=> {return false;});
}
```